# Django sorting and filtering objects in template based on url parameters

Tags: python, django

my problem is about sorting and filtering objects in .html template. I have both functions working but if I use one of them then second is not working.

My template:

```
<form action="{% url 'adverts' %}" method="get">
    <div class="form_field">
        <label for="formInput#search">Search Adverts</label>
        <input style="width: 400px;" class="input input--text" id="formInput#search"
               type="text" value="{{search_query}}" name="search_query" placeholder="Search by Adverts title, brand or description">
    </div>
</form>

<main>
<div class="search">
    <h2>Number of adverts: {{num}}</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'adverts' %}">
        <span>Sort by:</span>
        <select name="sort">
          <option value="new">newest</option>
          <option value="old">older</option>
          <option value="price_low">price low</option>
          <option value="price_high">price high</option>
          <option value="mileage_low">mileage lowest</option>
          <option value="mileage_high">mileage higher</option>
          <input type="submit" value="Sort">
        </select>
      </form>


{% for advert in adverts %}
<div class="mainAdvert">
    <a href="{% url 'single-advert' advert.id %}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="{{ advert.featured_image.url }}" class="advertImage">
        </div>
        <div class="column1">
            <span class="titleAdvert"><b>{{advert.title}}</b></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.year_of_production}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.mileage}}km</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.fuel_type}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.variant}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.created}}</li>
                </ul>
                <span class="location"><img class="address-icon" src="images/pin.png" alt="" /><b>Adres: </b>Rogowo, Poland</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span><h2 class="price">{{advert.price}}PLN</h2></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py function:

```
def adverts(request):
    page = 'adverts'
    adverts, search_query = searchAdverts(request)

    adverts = Advert.objects.all()
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort')

    if sort_by == 'new':
        adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    elif sort_by == 'old':
        adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('created')
    elif sort_by == 'mileage-high':
        adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('-mileage')
    elif sort_by == 'mileage-low':
        adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('mileage')
    elif sort_by == 'power-high':
        adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('-power')
    elif sort_by == 'power-low':
        adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('power')
    else:
        adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('-created')

    num = len(adverts)
    context = {'adverts': adverts, 'num': num, 'page': page, 'search_query': search_query}
    return render(request, 'adverts/adverts.html', context)
```

and my utils.py function for searching:

```
from .models import Advert, Brand
from django.db.models import Q


def searchAdverts(request):
    search_query = ""

    if request.GET.get('search_query'):
        search_query = request.GET.get('search_query')

    brands = Brand.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_query)

    adverts = Advert.objects.distinct().filter(
        Q(title__icontains=search_query) |
        Q(description__icontains=search_query) |
        Q(brand__in=brands)
    )

    return adverts, search_query
```

I think problem is in 'adverts' variable. Because I'm passing it to my template. And I'm using only variable from sorting.
`adverts = Advert.objects.all()`
I was trying to change 'adverts' on another name for sorting and I passed it in my template.. something like this:

```
{% if ... %}
{% for advert in adverts %}
<div class="mainAdvert">
    <a href="{% url 'single-advert' advert.id %}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="{{ advert.featured_image.url }}" class="advertImage">
        </div>
        <div class="column1">
            <span class="titleAdvert"><b>{{advert.title}}</b></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.year_of_production}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.mileage}}km</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.fuel_type}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.variant}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.created}}</li>
                </ul>
                <span class="location"><img class="address-icon" src="images/pin.png" alt="" /><b>Adres: </b>Rogowo, Poland</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span><h2 class="price">{{advert.price}}PLN</h2></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% else ... %}
{% for advert in adverts2 %}
<div class="mainAdvert">
    <a href="{% url 'single-advert' advert.id %}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="{{ advert.featured_image.url }}" class="advertImage">
        </div>
        <div class="column1">
            <span class="titleAdvert"><b>{{advert.title}}</b></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.year_of_production}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.mileage}}km</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.fuel_type}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.variant}}</li>
                    <li class="header">{{advert.created}}</li>
                </ul>
                <span class="location"><img class="address-icon" src="images/pin.png" alt="" /><b>Adres: </b>Rogowo, Poland</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <span><h2 class="price">{{advert.price}}PLN</h2></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Is it a good idea? Or maybe I just need to change mu function? I want for example search for 'audi' and sort results from oldest in the same template.

Comment: What is not working with your view? What problem do you face?

Comment: I have search and sort form. When I'm trying to search for some objects then it's not working. But when I'm trying to sort objects then everything works fine. I want to be able to sorting and searching for objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your adverts function is always writing over your searchAdverts as you're assigning a new query to the same variable.

```
adverts, search_query = searchAdverts(request)

adverts = Advert.objects.all()
sort_by = request.GET.get('sort')
```

Here you set adverts to the filtered query in the first line, then straight away you set adverts to Advert.objects.all() making your searchAdverts(request) call redundant, step one is stop doing this.

Secondly you are using Django lazy querying poorly. Again you are reassigning adverts after assignment meaning you're assigning the same variable 3 times without using it. When you write adverts = Advert.objects.all() in Django you are not actually calling that query, you are just preparing it as such, this means you can then add more filters, ordering etc after the initial assignment without doing extra db queries so the main part of your adverts can be written like this:

```
 adverts = Advert.objects.all()
 sort_by = request.GET.get('sort')

 if sort_by == 'old':
        adverts = adverts.order_by('created')
    elif sort_by == 'mileage-high':
        adverts = adverts.order_by('-mileage')
    elif sort_by == 'mileage-low':
        adverts = adverts.order_by('mileage')
    elif sort_by == 'power-high':
        adverts = adverts.order_by('-power')
    elif sort_by == 'power-low':
        adverts = adverts.order_by('power')
    else:
        adverts = adverts.order_by('-created')
```

This makes your adverts = Advert.objects.all() line actually be used and makes your code a bit cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this makes code more cleaner. Thanks for help. I've made very simple change and I have my function code like this now:

```
def adverts(request):
    page = 'adverts'
    search_query = ""

    #searching
    if request.GET.get('search_query'):
        adverts, search_query = searchAdverts(request)
    else:
    #sorting
        adverts = Advert.objects.all()
        sort_by = request.GET.get('sort')

        if sort_by == 'new':
            adverts = adverts.order_by('-created')
        elif sort_by == 'old':
            adverts = adverts.order_by('created')
        elif sort_by == 'mileage-high':
            adverts = adverts.order_by('-mileage')
        elif sort_by == 'mileage-low':
            adverts = adverts.order_by('mileage')
        elif sort_by == 'power-high':
            adverts = adverts.order_by('-power')
        elif sort_by == 'power-low':
            adverts = adverts.order_by('power')
        else:
            adverts = adverts.order_by('-created')

    num = len(adverts)
    context = {'adverts': adverts, 'num': num, 'page': page, 'search_query': search_query}
    return render(request, 'adverts/adverts.html', context)
```

And now everything works as I wanted :D

Comment: well done on that!